# jacksonbind objectnode adding extra double quotes while setting in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, jackson-databind

i have a template yaml file with the following content

```
 build:
  script:
   - "echo \"Utilizing external YAML file\"".     
   - !reference [ .build_java_gradle, script ]
```

I am reading this content and setting into another yaml file. But here its getting set with "" added to the reference as follows.

```
 build:
  script:
   - "echo \"Utilizing external YAML file\"      
   - "!reference [ .build_java_gradle, script ]".  <=== double quotes
```

I want to retain the same string without double quotes while setting into another yaml file. I am using jackson binding libraries.

```
ObjectNode buildNode = (ObjectNode) templateNode.get("build")
ObjectNode buildGitNode = gitlabCIYmlRootNode.putObject("build");
buildGitNode.setAll(buildNode);
```